# Facebook IOS SDK FBWebDialog

Tags: ios, facebook

I am experiencing an awkward behavior with FBWebDialog while showing the dialog itself for inviting users to my application (apprequests).

When the dialog shows up, the facebook app opens up and just stays there, if I go back to my application the dialog is still open as it should be.

```
FBFrictionlessRecipientCache *friendCache = [[FBFrictionlessRecipientCache alloc] init];
[friendCache prefetchAndCacheForSession:nil];

NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: userid, @"to", nil];
[FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession: nil
 message:@"my message"
 title:nil
 parameters:params
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
         }
     }
 } friendCache:friendCache];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out the problem.

The scenario is that my app is hybrid, so I have `file://` schema to make through my `HTML`.
I am using this method to "bridge" Native functionalities:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate =
    (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSLog(@"URL:%@", url);
    if ([url.scheme  isEqualToString:@"fb"]) {
        NSArray *splitUrl = [url.absoluteString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        [self inviteWithUserid:[splitUrl objectAtIndex:3]];
    } else if ([url.absoluteString  isEqualToString:@"utils://showFriendDialog"]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@""
                              message:@"Você já tem um jogo criado com essa pessoa."
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I set the string `fb://` to handle the invite funcionality. But I had no idea that `fb://` passing through the Webview delegate assumes that facebook app should open.

To solve the problem I changed the shceme to something else than fb:

```
if ([url.scheme  isEqualToString:@"myinviteschema"])
```

and it worked :)